# Python button debounce negated by XTE?

Tags: python

Hye all, I'm working on building a photo kiosk using a raspberry pi, some buttons, and some python.  I'm not a programmer, but have muddled my way through to this point.

Right now, I have the script shown below.  I'm attempting to use buttons hooked up to the Raspberry Pi's GPIO, to trigger key presses to control the photo slideshow.

As it stands, I have buttons working (with debounce), when they just print "Button 1" etc.  But when I add an XTE line to each button's function, the debounce stops working, and I get 3-4 hits for every button press.

Anyone know how I can get this working? Or if there's a different/better way to translate the GPIO signals into keypresses? (I tried Uinput for a while, but that didn't work)

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


### IMPORTS ###
import os                           # Allows us to run console commands and programs
from time import sleep                        # Allows us to call the sleep function to slow down our loop
import datetime                           # Allows us to look at the time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO                        # Allows us to call our GPIO pins and names it just GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                        # Set's GPIO pins to BCM GPIO numbering

b1count = 1
b2count = 1
b3count = 1

### GPIO SETUP ###
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)            # Set input pin to use the internal pull down resistor
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)            # Set input pin to use the internal pull down resistor
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)            # Set input pin to use the internal pull down resistor


### BUTTON PRESS FUNCTIONS ###
def Input_1(channel):
    os.system('xte "key q"')                     # Xte converting button Presses into Keystrokes.
    global b1count                        # Imports global variable set above
    now = datetime.datetime.now()                  # What time is it now?
    print ' - Button 1 - %r - %r' % (b1count, now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))   # Prints which button was pressed, how many times, and timestamps it
    b1count = b1count+1                        # Increments button count


def Input_2(channel):
    os.system('xte "key h"')                     # Xte converting button Presses into Keystrokes.
    global b2count                        # Imports global variable set above
    now = datetime.datetime.now()                  # What time is it now?
    print ' - Button 2 - %r - %r' % (b2count, now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))   # Prints which button was pressed, how many times, and timestamps it
    b2count = b2count+1                        # Increments button count

def Input_3(channel):
    os.system('xte "key v"')                     # Xte converting button Presses into Keystrokes.
    global b3count                        # Imports global variable set above
    now = datetime.datetime.now()                  # What time is it now?
    print ' - Button 3 - %r - %r' % (b3count, now.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))   # Prints which button was pressed, how many times, and timestamps it
    b3count = b3count+1                        # Increments button count


### BUTTON PRESS DETECTION ###
### Does a Callback to the appropriate Input function.  Also debounces to prevent clicking the button multiple times a second.
GPIO.add_event_detect(23, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Input_1, bouncetime=1000)   # Waiting for Button 1 to be pressed.
GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Input_2, bouncetime=1000)   # Waiting for Button 2 to be pressed.
GPIO.add_event_detect(25, GPIO.FALLING, callback=Input_3, bouncetime=1000)   # Waiting for Button 3 to be pressed.


### FEH -D - Slideshow -Z - Zooms -Y Hides Pointer -F Fullscreen -r loads all images in the following directory###
os.system('feh -D 0.25 -Z -Y -F -r /home/pi/Desktop/Pics/')         # Runs Feh Image Viewer with some command line arguments.


### Starts a neverending loop otherwise the script will just quit.
while True:
    print "Waiting for input."                     # Insert Random Loop Junk
    sleep(60);                           # Sleeps for a minute to save CPU cycles.  Any interrupt will break this.

GPIO.cleanup()
```